# Application level proxy on HTML. Capabilities

Tags: http, proxy

I am studying for a network security exam. I found in an old exam the following question and I have no idea of the answer:

> A company is protecting its intranet by a multi-homed bastion host B, acting as an application-level proxy.
>   Provide short answers (2 lines max) to the following questions.
>
> - Can B allow HTML incoming files and deny incoming JPG files in HTTP connections?
> - Can B allow HTML incoming files and deny incoming JPG files in HTTPS connections?
> - Can B allow HTML incoming files and deny incoming JPG files in HTTP VPN-connections?

I think that the answer is *“no”* for all the three question… but I would like to know for sure.

Comment: What is an HTTP VPN-connection?

Comment: @mikeazo Regular HTTP connection(s) routed via VPN (virtual private network) server(s).

Comment: @e-sushi, that is what I thought. Now the question is, where is the VPN server?

Comment: @mikeazo Normally de-located from user. Think proxyfied connection via off-site relay server. (3rd-party attack vector possible; meaning “MITM vulnerable” unless VPN is trusted and/or 100% user-controlled.)

Answer (score 3):

Technically all three "could" be yes if the SSL and VPN connections are terminated on B at the application proxy.

Without terminating the encrypted connections on B or using a key to decrypt the connections at point B only the first one would be true as in case 2 and 3 the proxy in theory could not see the traffic within the encrypted sessions to be able to differentiate between the .jpg and .html files.

A real-world example of this might be if you used mod_security on a proxy server as B to filter .jpg files from a web-server behind it.

This said I think the original question you read needs to have better clarification. Or you need to be specific about the encryption cases in all of your answers to make up for the lack of specificity in the original question.

Comment: Because all JPEG files are named with a jpg extension? I suspect the person whom wrote the test believes the first option to be true, but its not trivial, in practice, to block files based on their content.

Answer (score 1):

1) A "JPG file" can be identified by the extension on the HTTP request, and that's trivial for a proxy to block.  But extensions are not very significant on the web, so what a proxy should really be looking for is when the web server returns data with content type "image/jpeg", at which point it can choose to take alternative action.  But content type headers are not the final word either; browsers will not rely solely on the content type headers.  An img tag will cause the browser to make a request to the resource indicated in the src attribute, and it will do its best to display the data returned as an image, regardless of the content type header (which may be wrong due to misconfiguration or as an act of malice).  So a proxy that really wanted to block JPEG data would need to examine the body of every response.  JPEG file headers are pretty easily identifiable, so this wouldn't be too hard.

2) If the connection is end-to-end encrypted, it can't see or modify the data.  It's not uncommon for a corporate firewall to actively man-in-the-middle HTTPS connections, generating site certificates signed with a root certificate that has been pushed out to all of the workstations.  In this case, it's the same as case 1.

3) The question implies to me that the VPN tunnel is terminated before B.  Then what B sees is unencrypted HTTP, same as case 1.